# How to add new user to db.json

Tags: javascript, rest, vue.js, vuejs2, components

I have db.json, whick looks like:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "isActive": true,
      "balance": "$2,309.20",
      "picture": "http://placehold.it/128x128",
      "age": 26,
      "accessLevel": "guest",
      "firstName": "Robin",
      "lastName": "Whitaker",
      "company": "REMOTION",
      "email": "robin.whitaker@remotion.com",
      "phone": "+7 (845) 419-3899",
      "address": "442 Hanson Place, Tonopah, Washington, 5118",
      "about": "Ut occaecat cillum esse eu Lorem sit dolore. Fugiat cillum occaecat ad consequat ex irure velit ullamco occaecat Lorem fugiat qui consectetur do. Proident sunt eu sint cupidatat quis. Fugiat ad sunt eu sint velit anim eiusmod commodo incididunt excepteur deserunt ex exercitation. Mollit sunt incididunt sint ut et.",
      "registered": "21.03.2016"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "isActive": true,
      "balance": "$2,746.85",
      "picture": "http://placehold.it/128x128",
      "age": 22,
      "accessLevel": "guest",
      "firstName": "Richardson",
      "lastName": "Adkins",
      "company": "OCEANICA",
      "email": "richardson.adkins@oceanica.me",
      "phone": "+7 (902) 517-3328",
      "address": "117 Beverley Road, Maxville, South Dakota, 6701",
      "about": "Nulla nulla do cillum dolore commodo incididunt laborum labore laboris nisi cillum cillum do. Lorem exercitation nisi proident est adipisicing adipisicing eiusmod labore velit pariatur id enim. Aliquip fugiat adipisicing et dolor eu minim irure anim ea cupidatat. Pariatur magna duis ullamco anim culpa nisi nostrud.",
      "registered": "12.04.2014"
    }
   ]
}
```

Also, I have a form, in which i could add a user, it looks like

[image]

I am trying to add a new user into db.json:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h3>Add user</h3>
        <hr>
        <template>
            <user-form-add v-model="user" /> // userForm on the PICTURE!
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" @click="save">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @click="cancel">Cancel</button>
        </template>

    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import axios from '@/axios.js'
    export default {
        name: 'AddUserPage',
        components: {
            UserFormAdd: () => import('@/components/UserFormAdd.vue')
        },
        data:() => ({
            user: {
            },
            restUrl: '/users'
        }),
        computed: {
            id() {
                return null
            },
            url() {
                return `${this.restUrl}/${this.id}`
            }
        },
        methods: {
            redirectToList () {
                this.$router.push('/users')
            },
            save() {
                axios
                    .put(this.url, this.user)
                    .then(() => this.redirectToList())
                    .catch(error => `Error: ${error}`)
            },
            cancel() {
                this.redirectToList()
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

So, when i try to save, console told me:

> PUT /users/null 404 1.492 ms - 2

And, for example, if I set `id` as

```
id() {
    return 0
}
```

In my db.json the first object is replaced with a new one:

> PUT /users/0 200 1.397 ms - 143

What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sounds like you need to either determine the next free `id` or change your server PUT code so it catches `/null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **save a user/create a user** you should use **post request**. You don't need to pass id. And if you want to **update your user** then you need to **put a request** with the current **user id**.

Comment: OMG :) i tried using `POST request`, but I din't delete `{$this.id}` in the code, thanks a lot!)

Comment: You also need to change url like this - url() {
                return `${this.restUrl}`
            }